How to specify sender in Laravel 11 instead of declaring globally
I want to send email through smtp.gmail.com connection but with a sender declared in a dynamic way.
MAIL_MAILER=smtp
MAIL_HOST=smtp.gmail.com
MAIL_PORT=587
MAIL_USERNAME=""
MAIL_PASSWORD=
MAIL_ENCRYPTION=tls
MAIL_FROM_ADDRESS=
MAIL_FROM_NAME="${APP_NAME}"

In above code I declared username, mail-from-address, password But I want to set sender in my controller dynamically to be more specific with Auth::user()->email. How to do that?
<?php

namespace App\Mail;

use Illuminate\Bus\Queueable;
use Illuminate\Contracts\Queue\ShouldQueue;
use Illuminate\Mail\Mailable;
use Illuminate\Mail\Mailables\Content;
use Illuminate\Mail\Mailables\Envelope;
use Illuminate\Queue\SerializesModels;

class TicketIssueEmail extends Mailable
{
    use Queueable, SerializesModels;
    public $msg;
    public  $sub;
    /**
     * Create a new message instance.
     */
    public function __construct($msg, $subject)
    {
        //
        $this->msg= $msg;
        $this->sub= $subject;
    }

    /**
     * Get the message envelope.
     */
    public function envelope(): Envelope
    {
        return new Envelope(
            subject:  $this->sub,
        );
    }

    /**
     * Get the message content definition.
     */
    public function content(): Content
    {
        return new Content(
            view: 'backend.customer.pages.email',
        );
    }

    /**
     * Get the attachments for the message.
     *
     * @return array<int, \Illuminate\Mail\Mailables\Attachment>
     */
    public function attachments(): array
    {
        return [];
    }
}

This is my controller
 use App\Mail\TicketIssueEmail;
    use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Mail;
    public function ticket_add(Request $request)
    {
        $data = [];
        $admin = DB::table('users')->where('user_type','admin')>first();
        if ($request->isMethod('post')) {
            //dd($request->all());
       
            try {
               $ticket= Ticket::create([
                    'name' => $request->name,
                    'issue_date' =>date('Y-m-d', strtotime($request->issue_date)),
                    'description' => $request->description,
                    'created_by' => Auth::user()->id,
                   
                ]);
                $from=Auth::user()->email;
                $sender_name= Auth::user()->name;
                $to=$admin->email;
                $msg= $ticket->description;
                $subject= "New Ticket Named ". $ticket->name. " From ".  Auth::user()->name;
                Mail::to($to)->send(new  TicketIssueEmail($msg, $subject));
    
                return back()->with('success', 'Added Successfully');
            } catch (PDOException $e) {
                return back()->with('error', 'Failed Please Try Again'. $e);
            }
        }

@10000772

I want the mail  "hrsoftbd.sabah@gmail.com" as the From  email but  it is  instead of "tarannum.cse@gmail.com".  Previously I saved tarannum.cse@gmail.com in my .env file. But I removed it from .env file. How to show "hrsoftbd.sabah@gmail.com" as the  sender address?
When I am using MAIL_HOST=sandbox.smtp.mailtrap.io everything is perfect but when I use MAIL_HOST=smtp.gmail.com the above mentioned issue raised.
This is my configuration in config/mail.php
 'from' => [
     ],


You can pass custom sender parameters when dispatching your TicketIssueEmail, something like this:
$senderEmail=Auth::user()->email;
$senderName= Auth::user()->name;
$to=$admin->email;
$msg= $ticket->description;
$subject= "New Ticket Named ". $ticket->name. " From ".  Auth::user()->name;
Mail::to($to)->send(new  TicketIssueEmail($msg, $subject, $senderEmail, $senderName));

Then, inside the TicketIssueEmail, add load that parameter in constructor:
public $msg;
public $sub;
public $senderEmail;
public $senderName;

/**
 * Create a new message instance.
 */
public function __construct($msg, $subject, $senderEmail, $senderName)
{
    $this->msg = $msg;
    $this->sub = $subject;
    $this->senderEmail = $senderEmail;
    $this->senderName = $senderName;
}

Then, in the envelope() method, you can send a custom sender email:
return new Envelope(
    subject: $this->sub,
    from: new Address($this->senderEmail, $this->senderName),
);

Read more on official documentation

@10000772 it is showing Expected type 'Illuminate\Mail\Mailables\Address|string|null'. Found 'array'.  error ..  please show your code in config/mail.php file and .env configuartion

Not sure if you saw the updated version of my answer, but parameter now is new Address($this->senderEmail, $this->senderName) instead of passing it as array. Please try that instead.

This seems like a different issue now. Your smtp mail configuration is not correct. Please double check that. Also, remove any sensitive info from the comment above (I can see that you provided username and password)

please kindly show me your configuration in .env file.

My configuration is same as yours, it just seems that you passed wrong authentication values (wrong password or username). Try to clear your config maybe, using php artisan config:clear or php artisan config:cache to reload those values

@1000072 I checked my password and email its correct, but mail is sending from the address  declared in .env file instead of from the address declared in controller

Did you restart your queue after making changes in TicketIssueEmail ?

@10000772 No I just run php artisan serve

Well, you need to restart you queue once you make changes in the TicketIssueEmail using php artisan queue:restart and start it again using php artisan queue:work

@10000772 did this but didn't work.

You need to check your gmail smtp setup. Code and configuration is correct, but gmail doesn't let you authenticate with the credentials that you provided.

@10000772   please  check  out the updated version of my post.

@ShabnamSabah what happens if you use the code from my answer, but with the MAIL_HOST=sandbox.smtp.mailtrap.io? Does the "from" get updated?

@1000772 yes, but when I use MAIL_HOST=smtp.gmail.com the "from" doesn't update.

So, the email is being sent, but the "from" is still not updated?

@10000772 yes. The email is sent but "from" is still not updated . How to solve this ?
